# sendAs vs directory API alias

Tags: gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

If I set a users aliases using `DirectoryService.users().aliases()`, is there any reason to set the `sendAs` using `Gmail.users().settings().sendAs()`? I don't need to set any signatures or anything using the Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one reason to set the `sendAs` using `Gmail.users().settings().sendAs()` is if you want the user of that Google account's Gmail mailbox to send mail with a "`From:`" header that specifies the `sendAs` address.